# Laravel message as an array or json from request

Tags: laravel-5

I need an output  from laravel request validation error message as a json,

```
{
   message:[{field1 : error message},{..},....{field n : error message}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Laravel's default app boilerplate, you're all set: Laravel already decides which response type to give when validating request input. If you're using AJAX, it will respond with JSON in a format very similar to what you need; if you're using normal requests, it will redirect to a URL of your choice (or back, by default), flashing errors and input.

All you have to do is make sure your controller extends the default `App\Http\Controller.php` and on your validating method do something like this:

```
public function processMyForm()
{
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        // ...
    ];

    $this->validate(request(), $rules);

    // Request is valid, proceed
}
```

If the request is not valid, the controller will throw an exception, so the code below it will never execute.

If you're not extending the default controller, make sure your custom controller uses the `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` controller `trait`.

Comment: I need workout in the request file as well as in the rule() and i'm expecting output as i already discussed above.

Comment: Okay... My question is , We have a request file in laravel and it's giving the rule() default. Am i correct..? It's throwing error if validation fails.. That output style would be changed into above my required style.. Can we change it..? Please run the default request file with rule() and tell suggestion.